# Nginx connect to expressjs with a specific location

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to get nginx to work as a reverse proxy.

I want to have a virtual server at `hostname/service`, which connects to a NodeJS server sitting at port 5000.

If I try:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    location /service {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5055;
        (...)
     }
}
```

When I try to connect, I get a 404, saying there is no `/service` file. However I'm pretty sure that it is NodeJS that is responding to me.

So the problem is that, the request to `/service` to nginx is proxied to a request `/service` to NodeJS. How do I translate a request to `/service` to a request `/`?

Answer (score 0):

In your proxy_pass you are passing to port **5055** and you said above that you are running node at port **5000**.

Maybe just changing the `proxy_pass` to `http://localhost:5000;` could work.

Also, when you proxy to location `/service` all requests may also proxy with edge `/service`, as it says on nginx website

> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI:
>
> ```
> location /some/path/ {
>     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
> }
> ```
>
> Before version 1.1.12, if proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the original request URI might be passed instead of the changed URI in some cases.
>
> [read more here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

I usually use upstream to do this, following is a sample config I use which also proxies web socket connections properly.

```
upstream sample_app {
  server localhost:5000;
}

server {
listen 80 default_server;
location /service {
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"

     proxy_pass sample_app;
     proxy_redirect off;
 }
}
```

With this config if you go to `http://localhost/service` which automatically goes to port 80, it should pass request to node server running at 5000.